# dynamodb cannot get list of tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

I have created tables in AWS DynamoDB and grant the right to ec2 role in policy setting. However, when I run below code with java API, no table is returned. Is there anyone know what I should do?

```
AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider();

AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDB = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);
return dynamoDB.listTables().getTableNames().toString();
```

Comment: After I add the setRegion method, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by default the calls go to a "default region". Unless your tables are in the same region, this is expected. Better to set the region always.